# Is the following Alternating Series Absolutely Convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$$

I think it is Absolutely Convergent because it converges by direct comparison to Harmonic series? Am I right or wrong?

Comment: *it converges by direct comparison to Harmonic series* Are you sure? I think you misused the theorem.

Comment: It is not absolutely convergent.  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}$$, which diverges as seen from comparison to the harmonic series.

Comment: If you compare a series with the harmonic series, you hardly will find that the series is convergent.

Comment: Ohhh OK! Then how come the nth divergent test says that if "Lim = 0" then convergent? Isn't the harmonics series approaching zero?

Comment: The test says that if $\lim\neq 0$ then the series is divergent, but if $\lim=0$ then the series may be divergent or convergent.

Comment: Ohhh! Thank you so much. I've been having this confusion so much simply because I read the theorem wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**: $\left|\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right| = \dfrac{1}{2n+1} > \dfrac{1}{2n+2}= \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n+1}$

Answer (score 4):

The series $\sum_na_n$ converges absolutely if (by def) $\sum_n|a_n|$ converges.

Now
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right|=
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{2n+1}\ge
\frac12\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac1n=+\infty
$$
thus your series doesn't converge absolutely by comparison with harmonic series.

Answer (score 2):

This series does not converge absolutely. Writing out the first few terms of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right|,$$ it is $$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+...\geq \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}+...=-1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

$1/2$ plus the sum of the inverses of the odd numbers is greater than the sum of the inverses of the prime numbers, that is, $\infty$.

Comment: That is quite original approach. On the other hand, I would guess that the OP probably knows that harmonic series diverges, but they probably do not know about [sum of reciprocals of primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes). (Just guessing based on the level of the question.) So this answer might be not accessible to the OP. But it still can be interesting for other users.

Comment: I agree with @MartinSleziak